# Splitting a column data as per delimiter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark (1.4) dataframe where the data in a column is like "1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12". I want to split the data into multiple columns. Please note that the number of fields can vary from 1 to 12, its not fixed.
P.S. we are using Scala API.

**Edit:**

Editing over the original question. I have the delimited string as below:

```
"ABC-DEF-PQR-XYZ"
```

From this string I need to create delimited strings in separate columns as below. Please note that this string is in a column in DF.

```
Original column: ABC-DEF-PQR-XYZ
New col1 : ABC
New col2 : ABC-DEF
New col3 : ABC-DEF-PQR
New col4 : ABC-DEF-PQR-XYZ
```

Please note that there can be 12 such new columns which needs to get derived from original field. Also, the string in original column might vary i.e. some times 1 column, some time 2 but max can be 12.
Hope I have articulated the problem statement clearly.

Thanks!

Comment: does "12 such columns" above refer to the original string of digits, presumably not to the new text you introduced?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes it refers. For 12 new columns data is to be derived from the original field of table and also the example depicts how each of the columns will have data. If string not that big to have data in example columns 10,11,12 then those fields will hold blank data. So the length of the string in original field is dynamic, its not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` and `pivot`. Here is some sample data:

```
df=sc.parallelize([["1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12"], ["1-2-3-4"], ["1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10"]]).toDF(schema=["col"])
```

Now add a unique id to rows so that we can keep track of which row the data belongs to:

```
df=df.withColumn("id", f.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Then split the columns by delimiter `-` and then explode to get a long-form dataset:

```
df=df.withColumn("col_split", f.explode(f.split("col", "\-")))
```

Finally pivot on `id` to get back to wide form:

```
df.groupby("id")
  .pivot("col_split")
  .agg(f.max("col_split"))
  .drop("id").show()
```